# How kill all threads without access to threads on exit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

How kill all threads without access to threads on exit?
I use module threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are not killable in python.

You can use an alternative threading library, such as [kthread](https://pypi.org/project/kthread/).

Comment: Noting the kthread disclaimer _TERMINATING THREADS MAY INTRODUCE INSTABILITY OR OTHER UNDESIRABLE EFFECTS IN YOUR PROGRAMS._